# Understanding Kaon Mixing

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation

While studying Neutral-Kaon mixing, I learnt that the way we observe them is through their decays to Pions. But the states that decay are not the particles/antiparticles themselves but their mixture. $$ \left|K_{L}\right>=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left|K^{0}\right>+\left|\bar{K^{0}}\right>) $$  $$  \left|K_{S}\right>=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left|K^{0}\right>-\left|\bar{K^{0}}\right>)$$ Here, $\left|K_{L}\right>$ goes to two pions while$\left|K_{S}\right>$ decays to three pion system. The thing I don't understand is that in nature what exists in $\left|K^{0}\right>$ and $\left|\bar{K_{0}}\right>$; how do they sometimes combine to give a CP violating state and sometimes CP preserving?

Comment: I would like to add a question to this. How do we relate masses of $\left|K^{0}\right>$ and $\left|\bar{K^{0}}\right>$ to that of $\left|K_{L}\right>$and$\left|K_{S}\right>$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the way you look at them, there are several kind of kaons:

- $K^0$ and $\overline{K^0}$ are the kaons produced by strong interaction. They have a definite isospin and strangeness quantum numbers made respectively of $d\bar{s}$ and $\bar{d}s$. However they can oscillate meaning that they transform spontaneously in each other: $K^0 \leftrightarrow \overline{K^0}$ through a box diagram involving the weak interaction. Clearly, that means that $K^0$ or $\overline{K^0}$ cannot have a definite lifetime (since they transform continuously).
- $K_L$ and $K_S$ are the kaon having a definite lifetime, the ones propagating and observed in the detectors.
- $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the linear combinations of $K^0$ and $\overline{K^0}$ that are CP eigentates: $K_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(K^0 - \overline{K^0})$ and $K_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(K^0 + \overline{K^0})$. Kaons decay into 2 pions states or 3 pions states. It turns out that the CP quantum numbers are such that: $CP(2\pi) = CP(K_1)$ and $CP(3\pi)=CP(K_2)$.

So far so good. Now, experimentally when we create kaons via the strong interaction and detect them long time after their creation we know that what is detected are actually $K_L$, the only surviving kaons having a lifetime long enough to survive. If CP was conserved, you would expect to observe only:
$$ K_L = K_2 \to 3\pi$$
The equality $K_L=K_2$ results from phase space considerations: the phase space in the $2\pi$ states is much larger than in $3\pi$, so we expect $K_1$ to have a much smaller lifetime than $K_2$, thus the identification $K_L=K_2$. However, in 0.2% of the case we do observe $K_L \to 2\pi$. So what can you conclude?

- either, there is a direct CP violation: $K_L$ is really a $K_2$ CP eigenstate but CP is violated in the decay process itself allowing $K_2 \to 2\pi$,
- or there is an indirect CP violation: $K_L$ is not a pure $K_2$ but a mixture of $K_1$ and $K_2$:
  $$ K_L = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}}(K_2+\epsilon K_1)$$
  $\epsilon$ characterizing the amount of indirect CP violation. It turns out that **both violations exist**! In the kaon system the latter dominated (about 600 times larger than the former). But in other systems, like neutral B meson, direct CP violation is pretty common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this literature in their in books. I guess I didn't mention my problem clearly. Can you explain how $ K_{L}$and $K_{S}$ exist in nature. Is their any other way to detect one of these without looking at decay products?

Comment: yes, the lifetime of both kaons is long enough to reach the hadronic calorimeters. The $K_{s,L}$ then interact with the nucleon creating an hadronic shower. But you can't determine if this was a $K_S$ or a $K_L$. In addition, since they react via strong interaction it means that the $K_{S,L}$ are projected on $K^0$ or $\overline{K^0}$ by the detection...

Comment: Now, this is confusing. Answer a binary question. Which two are the physical states out of $\left|K^{0,\bar{0}}\right>$ and $\left|K_{L,S}\right>$?

Comment: both are physical states… If by physical state you mean state that propagate (having a definite lifetime), it is $K_{S,L}$. If by physical state, you mean the one that can be physically detected (or created) $K^0$ is the answer. As usual with QM, both exists, just a matter of the way they are observed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into some papers regarding how these two sets of states are detected.