# A case where entanglement leads to correlation in decay time

Tags: quantum-entanglement, randomness, half-life

Half-lives of unstable or metastable states are typically known, but specific decay times are inherently uncertain.

On the other hand, quantum entanglement leads to correlations between inherently uncertain variables

Is there some known example of multipartite quantum entanglement, where it leads to correlations in the decay times of distant parts?

Comment: This is probably not what you are asking for, but the iconic neutral [K meson system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367322/physics-of-k-meson) provides   two components $K_L, K_S$, each of which is an orthogonal entangled state of  $K^0$ and its conjugate. After the short components have decayed, the long ones, surviving to greater distances, will have comparable lifetimes when back-to-back.  Why is this unsatisfactory?

Comment: because the half-life is assumed to be known for a given state. If the decay times have same half-life but are otherwise distributed independently, then is not really a "correlation in decay time", or a rather trivial one

Comment: Indeed. Asking for synchronized decays is a bit much. Why would one?

Comment: Trying to understand what makes some uncertain variables susceptible to entanglement, and what makes some others insensitive to it