# What is the process transforming $K_L$ mesons into $K_S$ mesons?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, mesons

First of all, I could not find any good book/webpage where I can read about [K mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon), can somebody point me to a good reading?
The second point is about $K_L$ and $K_S$ mesons. As I can read, they are eigenstates of $K^0$ with opposite strangeness. In principle they should decay into pions, but I was wondering if a $K_L$ can spontaneously change into a $K_S$ instead of decay into pions or there would be an interaction with protons/nuclei needed for this transformation to occur.

Comment: [Your link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon#Regeneration) already explains regeneration: The freely flying $K_L$ and $K_S$ of course do not mix--that's the point of them being free hamiltonian eigenstates! But interaction of $K_L$ with a nuclear target regenerates $K_S$. What are you asking? [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210736/understanding-kaon-mixing?noredirect=1&lq=1). Have you tried *any* introductory ***book*** on particle physics?

Comment: my question is what is the _process_ taking place in the generation of K_S, could you explain it using a Feynmann diagram?

Comment: Again, there is ***no regeneration in vacuum***, as indicated in the WP article you cite, which has all the Feynman diagrams you'd ever need. The book by Perkins explains how, in matter, coherent strong interactions---think zillions of pions, gluons, etc---interact differently with the *notional* (fake, strong eigen-)states $K^0$ (elastic & charge-exchange scattering) and $\bar{K}^0$ (absorption)  so treat these two differently and "tilt" $K_L$ back to $K_S$ by a bit. But if you wish to further understand that, you must remove the crank stuff from your question and say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $K_L$s cannot spontaneously transform to $K_S$s in free space. They are eigenstates of the free hamiltonian and maintain their identity. Their mass difference is $\Delta m \sim 10^{-14} m$.  To effect a 
  $K_L\to K_S$ transformation ("regeneration") they must *go through matter and interact coherently and strongly* with its nuclei: absolutely nothing spontaneous about it. I would strongly recommend changing your title, as the present one is odd.

Let's ignore CP violation to avoid mission creep and muddying the waters in the process, so just *call* 
$$  |K_{L}\rangle \sim \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\left( |K^{0}\rangle - |\bar{K^{0}}\rangle \right)  \\   |K_{S}\rangle \sim\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(|K^{0}\rangle + |\bar{K^{0}}\rangle \right).$$

The $|K^{0}\rangle ,  |\bar{K^{0}}\rangle $ states are production states, that is they have well-defined strangeness, but they do not propagate or decay. The $|K^{0}\rangle\sim \bar{s} d$ is the isopartner of $K^+$, with *S=1*; while  the  $|\bar{K^{0}}\rangle\sim \bar{d}s$ is the isopartner of $K^-$, with *S=-1*.

They differ in strangeness by two, so only a doubly weak interaction mixes them, the celebrated box diagram. When this is  taken into account, the free eigenstates are $K_L, K_S$ with very different lifetimes, so a beam of neutral kaons will quickly purify to a beam of surviving $K_L$, which are longer lived. In vacuum, no conversion to $K_S$s.

As this beam enters a nuclear target,
the two "strongly distinct"  states (since strangeness is preserved in the strong interactions) are treated very very differently. The $K^0$ scatters its quarks by the exchange of gluons, pions, whatever, and exchanges quarks with the nucleons and back: elastic & charge-exchange scattering. You may write 137000 Feynman diagrams. Coherently, and then goes out, slightly diminished.

The $\bar{K^{0}}$ is different. It may do all of the above, but it also has additional channels: Its *s* quark may replace a nucleon quark to form a hyperon, *Λ* or *Σ*, so it is absorbed and gone. Whatever the hyperon does (decay), it does not return to the original state, so the absorption crudely degrades the $\bar{K^{0}}$ beam *more*, and increases strangeness, if you *must* think of it that way. (People would frown, with justice).

The crucial thing is that, since the two components of the $K_L$ wave function were absorbed and phase-shifted differently, many times (coherent scattering), the outgoing wave function is not $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\left( |K^{0}\rangle - |\bar{K^{0}}\rangle \right) $ anymore, but a slightly distorted version thereof. When resolved to free propagation eigenstates, the distortion amounts to a component of $K_S$ now present: $K_S$ has been regenerated after strong interaction with matter.

The standard textbook by [D. Perkins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521621968) should answer any questions you might have.

Comment: Is the 137000 number related to the fine structure constant? :p

Comment: Indeed; the secret handshake of physicists underscoring good-faith communication channels.